# redefining a single ruby method on a single instance with a lambda

Tags: ruby, oop

In Ruby, is there a way to redefine a method of a particular instance of a class using a proc?  For example:

```
class Foo
  def bar()
    return "hello"
  end
end

x = Foo.new
y = Foo.new
```

(Something like):

```
y.method(:bar) = lambda { return "goodbye" }

x.bar
y.bar
```

Producing:

```
hello
goodbye
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
def define_singleton_method_by_proc(obj, name, block)
  metaclass = class << obj; self; end
  metaclass.send(:define_method, name, block)
end
p = proc { "foobar!" }
define_singleton_method_by_proc(y, :bar, p)
```

or, if you want to monkey-patch Object to make it easy

```
class Object
  # note that this method is already defined in Ruby 1.9
  def define_singleton_method(name, callable = nil, &block)
    block ||= callable
    metaclass = class << self; self; end
    metaclass.send(:define_method, name, block)
  end
end

p = proc { "foobar!" }
y.define_singleton_method(:bar, p)
#or
y.define_singleton_method(:bar) do
   "foobar!"
end
```

or, if you want to define your proc inline, this may be more readable

```
class << y
  define_method(:bar, proc { "foobar!" })
end
```

or,

```
class << y
  define_method(:bar) { "foobar!" }
end
```

this is the most readable, but probably doesn't fit your needs

```
def y.bar
  "goodbye"
end
```

[This question is highly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135995/is-it-possible-to-define-a-ruby-singleton-method-using-a-block)

Comment: wondering why 'probably doesn't fit your needs' for the last solution?

Comment: Both: 
```
class Foo
end

obj = Foo.new

class << obj 
  def method1; end
end

def obj.method2; end

Comment: @AbdulRahmanK because he asked how to do it with a lambda, and that way doesn't use a lambda, but I wanted to include it anyway

Answer (score 31):

I'm not sure what version of Ruby this was added in (at least 1.8.7), but there seems to be an even simpler way of doing this:

```
str1 = "Hello"
str2 = "Goodbye"
def str1.to_spanish
  "Hola"
end
puts str1 # => Hello
puts str1.to_spanish # => Hola
puts str2 # => Goodbye
puts str2.to_spanish # => Throws a NoMethodError
```

Learnt about this whilst reading the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) (about_class_methods.rb lesson).
I'm still not entirely sure what the purpose of this is since it seems a bit dangerous to me.

Comment: Thank you for posting this (more) up-to-date answer !

Comment: Assuming `str.to_spanish` was already defined and I wanted to “redefine” it, how would I call the “original” `str.to_spanish` from within the newly defined one?

Comment: If `str` is your instance object and `String` is your class, you can call the class's version of the method by `String.to_spanish`

Comment: God I love Ruby

Answer (score 18):

You can use the syntax `class <<object` to get an object's "singleton class" (that's a special parent class belonging only to that object) and define methods only for that instance. For example:

```
str1 = "Hello"
str2 = "Foo"

class <<str1
  def to_spanish
    'Hola'
  end
end
```

Now if you do `str1.to_spanish`, it will return "Hola", but `str2.to_spanish` will give you a NoMethodFound exception.

Comment: if he has an externally defined proc in a simple variable, it's difficult to get it into the new scope created by class<<str1, without resorting to global or instance variables