# How can I access class variable in an instance?

Tags: ruby

look the demo code:

```
class A
  def method_a
    puts "this is method_a"
  end
end

class B < A
  def self.hide_method name
    if instance_methods.include? name
      @hidden_mthod ||= {}
      @hidden_mthod[name] = instance_method name
      undef_method name
    end
  end

  def self.invoke_hidden_methods
    puts @hidden_mthod.inspect
  end

  def bound_method name
    self.class.class_variable_get(:@hidden_mthod)[name].bind(self)
  end
end

b = B.new
b.method_a
B.hide_method :method_a
B.invoke_hidden_methods

b.bound_method :method_a  **#error**

b.method_a **#error**
```

The thing i want to do is rebind special method to the instance.but how can i access @hidden_method which defined in class with instance method?

**UPDATED:**
Thanks,Boris Strandjev, Ur really a nice man. as you above-mentioned, I think the code should be more simplified like this:

```
def bound_method name
  method_body = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@hidden_method)[name]
  self.class.send :define_method, name, method_body
end
```

Comment: By Boris Strandjev's answer.It still can't execute the last statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `bound_method` to:

```
def bound_method name
    self.class.instance_variable_get(:@hidden_mthod)[name].bind(self)
end
```

This is instance variable, not class.

**EDIT** As per your comment I did not solve your problem. So I had to rust off a lot of ancient ruby knowledge. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803020/redefining-a-single-ruby-method-on-a-single-instance-with-a-lambda).

And then I changed your method further:

```
def bound_method name
  puts self.class.instance_variable_get(:@hidden_mthod)[name]
  metaclass = class << self; self; end
  metaclass.send(:define_method, name,
             self.class.instance_variable_get(:@hidden_mthod)[name])
end
```

Basically `bind` will allow you to call this method on the instance once like:

```
self.class.instance_variable_get(:@hidden_mthod)[name].bind(self).call()
```

But does not add the method to the instance. `:define_method` does. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: You are right I was just trying to avoid the error and neglected your final goal. I will try to fix that now.

Comment: Ok found the solution you are looking for if I am not wrong. See my edit that will appear in seconds

Comment: Nice man!Thanks! I also updated the latest code in the thread.