# Is there a way to override a method of an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, overriding, instance

I have an instance variable in an active record class called `hash_value`. It's a serialized hash.

I want to display the hash as XML. Is it right to call `hash_value.to_xml`? Many nodes are numbers, and XML tags are not allowed to be only number (or start with a number).

I want to override the `to_xml` method of `hash_value`. I don't want to override on all hashes, just the hash that's in this record.

```
class ProductVersion < ActiveRecord::base
   serialize :hash_value, Hash

   def hash_value.to_xml
   end
end
```

I tried the answer here [redefining a single ruby method on a single instance with a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803020/redefining-a-single-ruby-method-on-a-single-instance-with-a-lambda)
but it doesn't seem to be applicable. I suspect because when I load the record, it creates a new `hash_value` object and thus the singleton adjustment on the original is moot.

Any thoughts would be great. 
I know I could write a function hash_value_to_xml, but I'd rather avoid doing something like that.

Thanks to the first comment, I came up with a solution. Not a good one, but one that works. I'd love to see if there's a better way, because this one smells a bit.

```
class MyHash < Hash
    def to_xml
      1/0 #to see if it's run. 
    end
  end
  def hash_value
    MyHash.new().merge(  attributes['hash_value'] );
  end
```

Comment: `hash_value` is not an instance variable, BTW. It's a method.

Comment: cool... that actually helps me suss it out. Not sure why I didn't remember that.

Comment: why the down vote?  I want to ask better questions, please tell me what about the question is bad.  Not enough code? Not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally go for `hash_value_to_xml` route. But since you insist, here's an idea that might work (haven't tested that)

```
class ProductVersion < ActiveRecord::base
   serialize :hash_value, Hash

   alias_method :old_hash_value, :hash_value

   def hash_value
     h = old_hash_value
     h.define_singleton_method(:to_xml) do
      # your custom xml logic here
     end
     h
   end
end
```

The idea is that you intercept value returned from `hash_value` and patch it on the fly.

Comment: I didn't do the alias I just used super, but man that was cool, and exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't want to go with the underscore version because I don't want my user to know they aren't getting the normal to_xml. Especially since the native to_xml returns invalid xml
E