# Calling original method from a redefined one

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

My question is based on an [answer to the topic “redefining a single ruby method on a single instance with a lambda”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804046/1626400).

**How can I redefine a method and from within the new method call the original definition?** Other instances of `some_object`'s class should not become affected.

```
def some_object.some_method
  # call original `some_object.some_method` here
  do_something_else
end
```

Comment: @AndrewPiliser I have seen that question before but to my understanding it is about redefining a method of all instances of a specific class whereas my question is about redefining a method on a specific object without touching behavior of any other objects. I have changed my question to make this a little clearer.

Comment: There is no such thing as a singleton method. Every method in Ruby is an instance method. What you call a "singleton method" is just an instance method of the singleton class. Every method in Ruby is an instance method in a class, thus there is nothing special, the question applies exactly. (And I'm not saying that because my answer is the accepted one, I don't care about the rep.) Once you understand that, Ruby all of a sudden gets a *lot* simpler.

Comment: @JörgWMittag [Your answer on the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/1626400) is great but very broad — perfect for a blog post. I feel like my question is different from the one linked above as that one is kind of open for interpretation (the ruby example seems invalid: `Foo` is defined twice and it's not completely clear whether he wants inheritance explained or change `Foo` instances (all of them/one of them?) at runtime. Considering how vague that question is formulated, your answer does in fact do it justice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `some_object.some_method` is not a singleton method, then you can just call `super` in your redefined method.

```
def some_object.some_method
  super
  do_something_else
end
```

If `some_object.some_method` is a singleton method, then

#### Ruby >= 2.0.0

You can define that method in a module

```
module SomeModule
  def some_method
    super
    do_something_else
  end
end
```

And then prepend it to the *singleton class* of the object

```
some_object.singleton_class.prepend(SomeModule)
```

#### Ruby < 2.0.0

You have to make an alias then redefine, since there is no `Module#prepend`.

```
class << some_object  # open the singleton class of some_object
  alias some_method_original some_method

  def some_method
    some_method_original
    do_something_else
  end
end
```

Comment: This [is in fact working well](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMEVqQVJsaW5qdGs) for me since it is not affecting other instances of `some_object`'s class.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Klass
  def greeting
    puts "hiya"
  end

  def add_personal_greeting(str)
    define_singleton_method(:greeting) do
      super
      puts str
    end  
  end
end
```

Bob gets a handle and tries the standard greeting.

```
bob = Klass.new
  #=> #<Klass:0x007fa66b084ad0> 
bob.greeting
  # hiya
```

He finds that too impersonal so he decides to add "I'm Bob" after the greeting. He does that by defining a method `greeting` on his singleton class that calls `Klass`'s instance method `greeting` and then adds another line to the greeting.

```
bob.add_personal_greeting("I'm Bob")
```

He tries it.

```
bob.greeting
  # hiya
  # I'm Bob
```

Much better. Note

```
bob.singleton_class.superclass
  #=> Klass
```

Meanwhile, Lucy tries the standard greeting.

```
lucy = Klass.new
  #=> #<Klass:0x007fa66a9ed050> 
lucy.greeting
  # hiya
```

She's not wild about it, but it will do.

Bob decides to change his greeting.

```
bob.add_personal_greeting("I'm Robert")
```

and tries it.

```
bob.greeting
  # hiya
  # I'm Robert
```

Comment: Interesting approach with `add_personal_greeting` and `define_singleton_method`. But if I only know `some_object`'s interface or if I do not have control over its class(es) (e.g. it's coming from some library I use) then this approach is not applicable, right?