# How to embed overwrite in jruby when I instantiate Java objects

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, overwrite

I want to overwrite some method when I instantiate a Java Object using ruby

when I use Java,the implement like this

```
Class name = new Class() {
    @overwrite
    public String method() {
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to implement like this in jruby when I use ruby to instantiate the instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803020/redefining-a-single-ruby-method-on-a-single-instance-with-a-lambda